# как подключить кастомный фонт в WPF из ресурсов

Tags: c#, wpf, шрифты, resources

вот стиль из ресурсов

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="TEST"/>
    <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Resources/slkscr.ttf #Silkscreen"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="50"/>
</Style>
```

вот файл, к которому подключаю стиль

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Label />
</StackPanel>
```

все проперти применяются, кроме FontFamily. как сделать так, чтобы применился шрифт?

вот подключение в проекте ресурса.

```
<ItemGroup>
<Resource Include="Resources\slkscr.ttf" />
```

Comment: `<FontFamily x:Key="Silkscreen">pack://appliction;,,,/Resources/#Silkscreen</FontFamily>`, дальше используйте где надо по ключу.

Comment: спасибо, помогло, очень не очевидно для меня было, нигде не находил такого, спасибо еще раз)

Comment: Я очень часто беру [данную](https://github.com/angelsix/fasetto-word/blob/164f022b89c60f2a72baa32fc33edb4bbf4f057b/Source/Fasetto.Word/Styles/Fonts.xaml) реализацию как шпаргалку, советую) Ну а так, напишите в ответ что у вас получилось, что бы вопрос не висел открытым.

Answer (score -1):

Открываешь шрифт(просто по шрифту двойной клик и шрифт должен добавлен в проект неважно в какой месте), находишь его имя и в коде просто в конструктор fontfamily передаешь имя шрифта как строку.

```cs
textBox.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Book Antiqua");

FontFamily = "Book Antiqua"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте блоки кода в ответах.